# How to get path to all leaves in adjacency list in python?

Tags: python, search, depth-first-search

I am trying to process an adjacency list in python. My requirement is to get get path to leaf nodes.

My list is

```
graph = {'A': set(['B', 'C']), 
         'B': set(['D']), 
         'D': set(['E']), 
         'F': set(['G'])}
```

I tried searching using dfs but it does not suite my requirement

```
def dfs(graph, node, visited):
    if node not in visited:
        visited.append(node)
        for n in graph[node]:
            dfs(graph,n, visited)
    return visited
```

I need the results as
[A, B, D, E]
[A, C]
[F, G]
That is A's child is B, B's is D and D"s is E hence A B D E 
A to C, since C has no children we stop 
F and G are related the sameway
Using the above function cause keyerror when processing node 'E'

Comment: In your graph Dictionary E is not a key. thats why graph[node] cause error when node = 'E'

Comment: Yes, that can be avoided. However it still does not get me what I am looking for